# Java EE web.xml: How to exclude a single page from a <url-pattern>

Tags: jsp, web.xml

I want on all pages BUT ONE (header.jsp) to include-coda like in this code:

```
<jsp-property-group>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
<include-coda>footer.jsp</include-coda>
```

I just don't get how I can limit the Pattern to exclude header.jsp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a more specific `url-pattern` which doesn't cover the `header.jsp`. E.g. put those JSPs in a folder and use `/foldername/*` as `url-pattern` instead. Or, give the JSP a different extension so that it doesn't match the `url-pattern`, e.g. `header.jspf` (JSP fragment).

Comment: The latter one has a problem. I can't use Java-Code when I changed the file-ending. It just doesn't get interpreted. I only use stuff like: ${request.title}